# OnClickListener assigns only at first element of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm creating my first app (TO-DO) which has a **RecyclerView** list of tasks. I want each task to have a delete button like in the picture:

[image]

When I try to add an onClickListener, it does, but only for the item in position 0.

Here is adapter code:

```
public class MainTabTasksAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

private ArrayList<Task> tasks;
private Context context;

public MainTabTasksAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Task> data) {
    tasks = data;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_task, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Task task = tasks.get(position);
    ViewHolder holderCast = (ViewHolder) holder;
    holderCast.taskTag.setText(task.getTag());
    holderCast.taskTime.setText(task.getNiceDate());
    holderCast.taskRepeat.setText(task.getNiceRepeatInterval());
//    holderCast.task = task;
//    holderCast.position = position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return tasks.size();
}


private class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    Task task;
    int position;
    private TextView taskTag, taskTime, taskRepeat;
    private ImageView btnTomorrow, btnEdit, btnDelete;

    ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        taskTag = v.findViewById(R.id.task_tag);
        taskTime = v.findViewById(R.id.task_time);
        taskRepeat = v.findViewById(R.id.task_repeat);
        btnDelete = v.findViewById(R.id.task_btnDelete);
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition(); // Thanks cricket_007
    //    tasks.remove(task);
        tasks.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}
}
```

## UPDATE

Okay, the problem was floatingActionMenu which I found on a github.
Even in the collapsed mode its size was the same when it was uncollapsed, and a click event occured on floatingActionButtons, but not on the buttons.

[image: Uncollapsed]
[image: Collapsed]

Comment: `int position;` is the same as `int position = 0;`, and you seem to have never set it to anything else...

Comment: It does, in the last line of onBindViewHolder method

Comment: I still could not solve the problem and I did not find a similar problems of other people. I think the best solution would be to rewrite the class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `int position`. (or `Task task;`)

All ViewHolder objects have a `getAdapterPosition()` method.

Try this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int position = getAdapterPosition();
    tasks.remove(tasks.get(position));
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's very useful method.
Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Try to print the value of `position` in the `onClick`

Comment: No reaction, seems like a listener is not being assigned to list elements except the first one.

Comment: How about inside of `onBindViewHolder`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to place this method in `onBindViewHolder()` method and remove onClick from `ViewHolder` class

```
holderCast.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

         }
    });
```